# Programmatically setting up a customer - Multi Select

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, import, programmatically

When creating a customer programmatically I know how to set a simple text field eg

```
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setFirstname('John');
```

However my question is how do I set the values of a multiselect field

Answer (score 1):

Just in case some one else pulls out their hair working this out you use 1 string with values comma seperated.

```
->setAllowedPaymentMethods('free,banktransfer')
```